# How to get Azure ML to execute Jupyter Notebook with Papermill

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

So, I'm sorta new to this, but I have just enough knowledge to be dangerous.  TLDR, I have a Jupyter Notebook that I need to parameterize and execute with Papermill.  I know Azure ML service can execute Jupyter Notebooks, but now I want to wrap it with Papermill.  Does Azure ML support Papermill?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that there are multiple ways to achieve this, here's how I'd do it:

- Use [Azure ML Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipelines-cli)
- Make sure your notebook is in the `code` directory
- Make sure the [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipelines-cli#environment) you run your pipeline in has Papermill installed
- Create a component that executes the notebook using either Papermill's Python API, or its CLI API.
- Schedule the pipeline or run it manually, whichever best suits you.

If you haven't created an AML pipeline so far, I'd recommend creating the simplest one you can, i.e. one that runs `echo "Hello World"` or something like that, and then expanding it to use a custom environment, and only using Papermill to render the notebook.

Comment: Thank you.  I still don't know how to create an ML Pipeline, but I think I have enough to stumble into the right direction.  I have successfully run my notebook with Papermill the other day and now I want to automate the notebook deployment and execution of notebook with parameters.   I might pick your brain later.

Comment: I have another question as I am gaining further understanding of AML: Should it be possible to containerize my source code (notebook, source code, papermill, etc.) to run from a compute target (compute instance, compute cluster, aks cluster, etc using one of the AML CPU Inference docker images?  Is there a Slack/Discord/Teams server to discuss this challenge?

Comment: Definitely possible, ideally you'd create a new question to discuss that, and to keep this question focused.

Comment: I got a reprieve from using the AksCompute since it's broken right now, so I can go back to using an AML Environment.  I've posted my modified question again at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367832/how-can-i-get-a-containerized-jupyter-notebook-to-run-code-within-azure-ml