# How can I get a Containerized Jupyter Notebook to run code within Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, docker, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm not an expert in Azure ML but I'll give as much detail as I can or understand.  The task I've been given is probably overkill for Azure Machine Learning, but I have a Jupyter Notebook that I have parameterized with Papermill.  There is NO training needed. It reads data from varying sources, processes it with parameters, generates and output.  I want to pass it parameters to produce said output. It works manually in a Compute Instance. Now I need to get it working in Azure ML in an automated fashion.

My plan is to create a custom docker image, store it in ACR, and then when ready to deploy: create an AML Envrionment, a Component, and an AML Pipeline that will call the component which will in turn all the executing script within the AML Environment container the custom container image.

I successfully created an AML docker image using a pre-build AML docker image. I can create a container for AML but those are usually for models and deployments which usually use pre-built docker images that AML have hooks into. So... is it possible to containerize my Jupyter Notebook into a docker container which can then be called from an AML pipeline?  Do I even need to use the pre-build docker images?  Do I even need the component and just call the container service directly from the AML pipeline?

The end user wants to schedule multiple jobs to pass varying arguments.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/minimal-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu-inference:latest

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV CONDA_ENV_DIR=/opt/miniconda/envs

# Switch to root to install apt packages
USER root:root

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    gnupg1 \
    gnupg2 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    tzdata \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

USER dockeruser

# Install python dependencies
COPY Docker-environment.yml /tmp/conda.yaml
RUN conda env create -n userenv -f /tmp/conda.yaml
#&& \
#    export SERVER_VERSION=$(pip show azureml-inference-server-http | grep Version | sed -e 's/.*: //')  && \ 
#    $CONDA_ENV_DIR/userenv/bin/pip install azureml-inference-server-http==$SERVER_VERSION

# Update environment variables
ENV AML_APP_ROOT=/app
ENV AZUREML_ENTRY_SCRIPT=run_papermill.py
ENV AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH="$CONDA_ENV_DIR/userenv" 
ENV PATH="$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/bin:$PATH" 
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

# Copy code
COPY src $AML_APP_ROOT

ENV WORKER_TIMEOUT=300
```

[image: Picture of Src folder]

"main.ipynb" Jupyter Notebook runs just fine on its own.  "papermill.ipynb" Jupyter Notebook is a simple wrapper that has parameters to pass to the main jupyter notebook file.  And "run_papermill.py" is another wrapper that actually needs to be called with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but if you want to run a job in a pipeline you can just create a `command` job. The simplest way is to use the `az ml` cli (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-cli?tabs=public)).

With it you just create a simple yaml file that describes you job, including the environment you want to use. See here for a [lot of examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-command#examples), one is even for using papermill:
For instance:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandJob.schema.json
command: |
  pip install ipykernel papermill
  papermill hello-notebook.ipynb outputs/out.ipynb -k python
code: src
environment:
  image: library/python:latest
compute: azureml:cpu-cluster
```

In this example, papermill is installed on each run of the job, but you should look at the other examples on how you can create your own environment without taking the hit of the `pip install` with every execution.

To run the job, you just execute it with the cli with this command:

```
az ml job create -f your_command_job.yaml
```

This will upload the `code:` folder (`src` in this example) and then put the `environment:` container on the `compute:`, cd to where the `code:` was placed and execute your `command:`.

That command job you can easily run in a pipeline -- see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-pipeline#examples) for lots of examples.

Hope this helps.